# How to set condition for the input from command line? (java)

Tags: java, shell, command, command-line-arguments, rgb

So I need to write a program that has 3 positive Integers between 0 and 255 as command line argument (the Input), How could I set those conditions? so far i wrote:

```
public class RGBtoCMyk {
public static void main(String []args){
   int r = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
   int b = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
   int g = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

  //now i must set the conditions, that r, g and b are between 0 and 255
  }
```

If you have any ideas please help me

Comment: What do you mean by setting, you mean filling it with user input?  If you have the file in RGBtoCMyk.java, use the command line: `javac RGBtoCMyk.java`, `java RGBtoCMyk <arg1> <arg2> <arg3>`

Comment: Well, what do you want to do if the user runs the program with arguments that don't match the conditions? Hint: they may not even be numbers, user can run with `java RGBtoCMyk foo bar baz`, and they can even try to run without arguments at all.

Comment: Or are you trying to ensure that the three values are between 0-255, in which case you can just use if statements and throw invalid argument exceptions if the numbers are out of range

Comment: Try to google about `if` statement

Comment: If the user puts in anything except a number, an exception will be thrown by `Integer.parseInt()`, you should only need to handle checking if it's 0-255, which you could do with `new Color(r, g, b)`, since that will check the inputs and throw the exception for you

Comment: As a side note, have a look at [Apache Commons CLI](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/) which provides some very helpful tools to build a commandline interface (CLI).

Comment: thanks for the sugestions!
yeah the 3 arguments must be in between 0 and 255, so i have set the condition.
i'll try using if Statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` to make sure you have enough input elements and `NumberFormatException` to make sure that you have `int` values. If you do not have one of those exceptions, you can check whether all the values are inside the given interval.

```
public class RGBtoCMyk {
public static void main(String []args){

    try {
    int r = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int b = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    int g = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

    if ((0 <= r) && (r < 256) && (0 <= b) && (b < 256) && (0 <= g) && (g < 256)) {
        System.out.println("Valid colors");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid colors");
    }

    //now i must set the conditions, that r, g and b are between 0 and 255
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException arrayIndexOutOfBoundsException) {
        System.out.println("Not enough input");
    } catch (NumberFormatException numberFormatException) {
        System.out.println("Inputs are not integer values");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may add a check condition, if your number is outside of the range then you can prompt the user that you can re enter.

There is no other way if they enter value > 255 and you want to reduce it. Here are the two options you can do.

1. Option 1 , if a user enters more than 255, consider it 255 and is value is less than zero consider it zero. In case he enters a string throw an exception.

   ```
   public class RGBtoCMyk {
   public static void main(String []args){
   try {
   int r = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
   int b = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
   int g = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

   r = r>255 ? 255:r;
   r = r<0 ? 0:r;

   g = g>255 ? 255:g;
   g = g<0 ? 0:g;

   b = b>255 ? 255:b;
   b = b<0 ? 0:b;
   }
   catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException arrayIndexOutOfBoundsException) {
   System.out.println("Not enough input");
   } catch (NumberFormatException numberFormatException) {
   System.out.println("Inputs are not integer values");
     }
    }
   }
   ```
2. Option 2 : Input the value again in case the value is not between 0 to 255

   ```
   public class RGBtoCMyk {
   public static void main(String []args){
   try {
   Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
   int r = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
   int b = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
   int g = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

   If(r>255 || r<0){
   System.out.println("Value Not in Range. Please Enter between 0 and 255");
    int usrInput=sc.nextInt();
    }

   //Similarly for g and b.
   b = b>255 ? 255:b;
   b = b<0 ? 0:b;
   }

   catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException arrayIndexOutOfBoundsException) {
   System.out.println("Not enough input");
   } catch (NumberFormatException numberFormatException) {
   System.out.println("Inputs are not integer values");
      }
     }
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few good ways to go about parsing input data.

### Usage Statement

If malformed input is detected, quit gracefully

```
if(args.length < 3)
{
    printUsage();
    return;
}
int r, g, b;
try
{
    r = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    g = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    b = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
}
catch(NumberFormatException e)
{
    printUsage();
    return;
}
if((r | g | b) >> 8 != 0) //same as these other two if statements
//if(((r | g | b) & 0xffffff00) != 0)
//if(r < 0 || r > 255 || g < 0 || g > 255 || b < 0 || b > 255)
{
    printUsage();
    return;
}
//put your code here, you have r, g, and b 0-255

//add in the printUsage method somewhere
public void printUsage()
{
    System.err.println("Input is 3 numbers, each 0-255");
}
```

### Errors Thrown

This is for if you don't feel like catching the errors and printing out things, but instead just letting the error be printed out to the console

```
int r = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
int g = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
int b = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
//at this point the program will have exited if 3 non-ints were passed, now check values
if((r | g | b) >> 8 != 0) //same as the other two if statements from before
    throw new IllegalArguementException("Color parameters outside of expected range (0-255)"); //mostly copied format from java.awt.Color
//do stuff with r, g, and b being 0-255
```

### Process Invalid Arguments

Another option is to format it so you can pass in 255, 0, 0 as just 255

The program will attempt to just keep on processing no matter what malformed input you give it

```
int r = 0;
int g = 0;
int b = 0;
try
{
    r = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    g = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    b = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
}
catch(NumberFormatException e){}
if(r >> 8 != 0)
    r = 0;
if(g >> 8 != 0)
    g = 0;
if(b >> 8 != 0)
    b = 0;
//or you could make it so that it takes the last bits, 256 would be 0, 257 would be 1, and so on...
//r = r & 0xFF;
//g = g & 0xFF;
//b = b & 0xFF;

//do stuff with your r, g, and b being 0-255
```